# How to loop over dynamically builded dropdowns and get their value in ASP.NET

Tags: vb.net, loops, select

I have multiple dropdowns in my frontend. (They're dynamically made so I don't know how many there will be and I can't call them by their id. My problem is how I can make a loop that checks every value of the select dropdown.

Generated HTML:

```
<div id=panel1" runat="server">
  <div class="border" runat="server">
    <select name="test1" id="test1" >
      <option value="0">Option 1</option>
      <option value="1">Option 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="border" runat="server">
    <select name="test2" id="test2" >
      <option value="0">Option 1</option>
      <option value="1">Option 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aspx code of how the html is generated:

```
Dim div71 As New Panel
div71.CssClass = "border"
Dim ddl As New DropDownList
ddl.ID = "select" & panel & "_" & counter
ddl.Items.Clear()
ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem("Select something", "0"))
ddl.CssClass = "colegas"
div71.Controls.Add(ddl)
Dim br As New HtmlGenericControl("br")
div71.Controls.Add(br)
Dim emailinput As New TextBox
emailinput.ID = "emailinput" & panel & "_" & counter
emailinput.CssClass = "form_txt2"
emailinput.Attributes.Add("PlaceHolder", "E-mail")
emailinput.Style.Add("margin-bottom", "8px")
emailinput.Style.Add("display", "none")
div71.Controls.Add(emailinput)
Dim hidder As New HiddenField
hidder.ID = "hidder" & panel & "_" & counter
div71.Controls.Add(hidder)
Panel1.Controls.Add(div71)
```

I'm thinking to do something like this but can't get my head around what exactly will work

```
For Each div In Panel1
  If select.value ="0" Then
    'do something
  Else
    'do something else
  Endif
Next
```

Comment: Is this ASP.NET and you want to do that on the server?

Comment: Yes it is and yes I want.

Comment: Why dont you use DropDownLists? Or is that just the generated html? Then show your aspx

Comment: That's the generated html, it's made in the backend, can't post is as a comment since it's too long.

Comment: if you want to access the control on the server you have to show the aspx code, otherwise i dont know the controls. Could be html control with runat=server or a dropdownlist. The div could be a panel

Comment: Okay I added it in the description, but I just thought it would make things unnecessary complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these are `DropDownLists` you can find all recursively with this code:

```
Dim allDropDownLists = New List(Of DropDownList)()
Dim controlQueue = New Queue(Of Control)()
controlQueue.Enqueue(Panel1)

While controlQueue.Count > 0
    ' traverse all children to find all DropDownLists
    Dim current As Control = controlQueue.Dequeue()
    For Each child As Control In current.Controls
        controlQueue.Enqueue(child)
    Next

    Dim ddl = TryCast(current, DropDownList)
    If ddl IsNot Nothing Then ' additional filters here
        allDropDownLists.Add(ddl)
    End If
End While
```

Now you can loop this list and do whatever you want:

```
For Each ddl In allDropDownLists
  If ddl.SelectedValue ="0" Then
    'do something
  Else
    'do something else
  Endif
Next
```

Of course you could do that also already in the `While`-loop without adding them to the list.

Comment: If I want to also put all my Textboxes (the emailinput Textboxes) in a list like you did with the DropdownList. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @ManuelvandenNotelaer: replace all occurences of `DropDownList` with `TextBox`?!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought but somehow this always gives back an empty list

Comment: @ManuelvandenNotelaer: are the TextBoxes really server controls(runat=server) and not html-input controls? If so, do you gerenate them dynamically or declaratively(on aspx). If dynamically, where do you gererate them and where do you try to find them?

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the div tags and used asp panel and dropdownlist controls and this piece of code worked for me to loop through the dynamically generated dropdownlist control. Hope this helps.

```
<asp:panel id="panel1" runat="server">
<asp:DropDownList id="test1"  runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Value="White"> White </asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="red"> red </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList> 
<asp:DropDownList id="test2"  runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Value="White"> White </asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="red"> red </asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>    
</asp:panel>
```

Vb.Net Code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)    Handles Me.Load
For Each sel As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList In 
panel1.Controls.OfType(Of System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)
        If TypeOf sel Is System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList Then
            MsgBox("The control is a button.")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```